# Phrases starting with "The Fruits of ...."

Tags: phrases, expressions, quotes

I was wondering if there were any other phrases starting with "fruits of ......"
like "fruits of labor" and "fruits of love"...
The phrases can have different meanings but they need to start with "fruits of".

Thank you

Comment: Labor, victory, science, peace, growth, democracy, success, research, globalization, sanctification, repentance, colonialism, decolonization, conquest, capitalism, civilization, independence, faith, life, productivity, empericism, liberty, progress, freedom, power, war, glasnost, hellenism. If you want me to go on for another hour, set up a WebEx or Skype call. Cheers.

Comment: @RegDwigнt — As you are a moderator could you explain the purpose of your comment in relation to the explicit injunction in the comment box to use comments to ask for clarification and not to use them to answer questions.

Comment: @Cascabel — Thank you for trying to help, but my question was addressed to the poster, not to you. I want to know his explanation and position, as a mod, not anyone else’s. I am not new to this list and this enquiry was made deliberately.

Comment: Then maybe you could take it up on meta, but I am sure that the majority of the users here will come down on the side of RegDwight. Comments are "fair game", so if you want privacy get a chat room.

Comment: @Cascabel — I do not wish to get into a conversation with you, but I have never said anything about privacy. Perhaps you will wish to reconsider that remark. Also [I am aware of meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/why-are-answers-being-posted-in-the-comments-on-the-question/8171#8171).

Comment: @David I am sorry if we got fighty. I have seen many of your posts, and I think you are  a very reasonable and thoughtful person. Can we just agree to dis-agree? BTW...extended conversation in comment is _also_ discouraged, but we do it all the time...

Comment: @david The comment indicates that there *are* many other phrases. And it leads the poster to clarify or rethink their question in some way. It's a form of platonic question. (And I don't see what's wrong with anybody replying to a comment that's been made publicly.)

Comment: @JasonBassford — Your interpretation of the comment from RegDwigнt  may or may not be correct. Likewise that from Cascabel. However he is surely capable of answering himself. And his is the only explanation that is of interest to me, because he is a moderator, responsible for helping to implement site policy which he appears to be violating. This has implications in relation to the requests made to me in the past to flag rather than comment on what I consider violations of site policy.

Comment: @David He's certainly capable of commenting. So, too, is everybody else who wishes to comment. And the public nature of the commenting system doesn't provide prohibit that in any way.

Comment: @JasonBassford — You seem to have misunderstood me. I really don’t care whether or what other people comment. However as Cascabel’s comment was addressed to me I was merely informing him (and anyone else) that I did not intend to get into a conversation with anyone other than RegDwigHt about the question I had put to him.

Comment: @David And, as was replied, if you did not want anybody's else's input, then you shouldn't have made a public comment...

Comment: @JasonBassford — I addressed a question to a specific person in public. I did not expect anyone else to reply on his behalf, but of course they are free to do so. However I am not obliged to reply to them, and my carefully phrased polite reply was to make that clear so they understood why I did not intend to do so. I am not thin skinned and I am an experienced street fighter, but comments is not the appropriate or my chosen arena.

Comment: @David If you object to somebody making a *public* reply in a *public* forum, then you should do so in meta, raise a flag, or simply not post publicly in the first place (instead, directly contact the person in private). I still fail to see why you are telling people they shouldn't be responding. However, further comment here seems to be going nowhere and simply belabouring the points that everybody's already made, so I will stop at this point. (But I will continue to reply publicly in order to provide input on public discussion, and I encourage others do so so too when they have an opinion.)

Comment: @JasonBassford — Do you really not understand what I am doing? I suspect RegDwigHt does.

Answer (score 1):

**fruit**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/75072?rskey=3d2gSi&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Anything accruing, produced, or resulting from an action or effort,
>   the operation of a cause, etc.

As in:

> 1849   Macaulay Hist. Eng.   The produce of the soil far exceeded the
>   value of all the other **fruits of human industry**.

and

> 1858   T. Carlyle Hist. Friedrich II of Prussia I. ii. vi. 119   His
>   going on the Crusade..was partly the **fruit of the life** she led
>   him.

As noted above in a comment, one can reap the fruit of many things.